# How can I combine external logins and two-factor authentication in ASP.NET Core Identity?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, two-factor-authentication, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm implementing authentication and authorization for a simple web application built with ASP.NET Core 3.1. So far, ASP.NET Core Identity meets the requirements except for one: the default implementation of external logins (in this case, Google) does not seem to work with the default implementation of Two-Factor Authentication.

When I log in using a local account (with 2FA configured), I am prompted for the TOTP token. When I log in using a Google account, there is no prompt for the second factor. I have spend a few days researching this (e.g. learn.microsoft.com, Google, and here on SO) but found nothing useful. How can I get ASP.NET Core Identity to use Two-Factor Authentication for users who log in with Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prerequisites:

- An ASP.NET Core project using ASP.NET Core Identity with one or more external login providers already configured and working, e.g. Google.

Here's how I got it working.

1. Use the [Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) procedure to override the Account/ExternalLogin page. (I also added that page to the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20191208153411/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio). Thanks, Internet Archive!)
2. Open the ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs file and locate the `OnGetCallbackAsync` method.
3. Find the call to `_signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync()` and change the `bypassTwoFactor` parameter from true to false.
4. Find the conditional statements which check the result of ExternalLoginSignInAsync(), and add this code:

   ```
       if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
       {
           return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
       }
   ```

Putting it all together, you should have something like this:

```
    // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
    var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor : false);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("{Name} logged in with {LoginProvider} provider.", info.Principal.Identity.Name, info.LoginProvider);
        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
    }
    if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
    }
    if (result.IsLockedOut)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
    }
    else
    {
        // existing code omitted for brevity
    }
```

Note: Since I was unable to find any documentation or examples on how to do this, I accept that my implementation may not be optimal. If you know a better way, please share!